# SparkUI cannot be reached while debugging in IntelliJ

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I am a newbie in Spark programming and developing a Spark application using IntelliJ IDE. What I want to achieve is reaching Spark Web UI while continuing debugging in IntelliJ. However, I'am getting "This site can't be reached" error when trying to reach the URL provided by SparkContext.

[image]

Is it possible to both monitoring the Spark Web UI and debugging in IntelliJ?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I've already tried http://localhost:4040 and http://localhost:8088. Also, I could reach Spark Web UI from http://localhost:4040 when starting spark-shell via command line interface.

Comment: same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

you can see your application on port :8088 ex: https://hostname:8088

Comment: I couldn't reach using this port either.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.
My observation is that when the program is running, you can still access the SparkUI on port 4040. But when you reach the breakpoint, you cannot -- probably because the program is suspended, but I am not very sure.

Hope this helps